# Composer Autoloading for classes without php extension

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm creating a composer package but my library uses a ".class.php" extension instead of the usual ".php" extension.

**E.g.** `BaseController.class.php` for `BaseController` class

As a result of this the Composer Autoloader is unable to find my files.

How do I fix this?

Comment: You could use always classmap, but you need to regenerate it after each class addding.

Comment: ok, I just looked into that and there are at least 50+ .class.php files inside my library. Is it recommended that I do this or should I just fork my library and rename all .class.php and .php and use that?

Comment: See ClassLoader.php inside composer folder. If I change this line to use '.class.php' it works!

>>  $file = $this->findFileWithExtension($class, '.php'); //line 303

Comment: Then use it as accepted answer

Comment: I wish I could but composer overwrites ClassLoader.php when I run it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of research there are two ways of doing it. Unfortunately neither is good enough but for now anyone who faces this problem can use it:

1. Rename all .class.php to .php if it is your own library
2. In line 303 of ClassLoader.php (inside composer folder) change `.php` to `.class.php`

`$file = $this->findFileWithExtension($class, '.php'); //line 303
 $file = $this->findFileWithExtension($class, '.class.php'); //line 303`

Hopefully there will be support for this in future versions!

Comment: Step 1 is the only correct course of action. Using class.php as an extension serves no purpose other than to make your code look outdated and antiquated.