# Is there an issue when you add .class.php inside filename of class with namespaces?

Tags: php, class, namespaces, composer-php, autoload

I am working with a project which for all classes it includes .class.php inside the name of that classfile.

I started using namespaces and it seems that using namespaces and composer autoloading in non .class.php files it works however when using namespaces in those .class.php files the file breaks?

I am unable to get any errors as this is disabled as this is a production application and I have no access to the php log files.

Comment: I think the file name should match the class name - so it expects `Foo` class to be in `Foo.php`

Comment: _“I am unable to get any errors as this is disabled as this is a production application and I have no access to the php log files.”_ - then set up a local test system first; _guessing_ what errors might have occurred is not a proper way to go about this.

Comment: Think https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27600213/composer-autoloading-for-classes-without-php-extension is useful.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I found that the issue is because of the duplicate extension. Having filename.class.php will cause an issue and autoloaded will not be able to load the class.